# How to deep add new key value pair object inside Immutable Js Map in redux..?

Tags: reactjs, object, redux, immutable.js

I trying to add new key value pair object one by one inside `items` as given below:

```
{
  appElements: {
    layers: {
      layer_1: {
        background: {
          width: '100px',
          height: '100px',
          bgColor: '#aaaaaa',
          bgImage: 'http:bgimage1.png'
        },
        items: {
          yrgroih9: {
             width: '100px',
             x: '200px'
           },
           qhy0dukj: {
             width: '100px',
             x: '200px'
           },
           '7lw2nvma': {
             width: '100px',
             x: '200px'
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Code used to add new object inside `items`:

```
case 'ADD_OBJECT':
  return state.setIn(["appElements","layers","layer_1","items"],{
    [action.objData.item_id]: {
      "width": action.objData.width,
      "x": action.objData.x
    },
  });
```

The first entry object trying to add inside `items` works perfect:

```
yrgroih9: {
  width: '100px',
  x: '200px'
}
```

Redux store data arranged (from chrome redux devtools):
[image]

But adding another object will **remove the first entry** and add the current entry.

Also tried `updateIn` function, its not working.

How to **add objects without removing the old one.?**

Comment: Are there any typos in your object? `layer_1` and `items` should be an array. Can you update the correct object structure?

Comment: There is no array based index.. Only Object key value pairs and that is the correct object structure i have added... I have added redux store objects as image file now for better understanding.. Help me..

Comment: So that's where the error go in, you have no `qhy0dukj` or `7lw2nvma` because these are ignored. `items` took `yrgroih9` as the key, and it only has one key since it is a hash.

Comment: @FiriceNguyen .. i am saying that the another object keys not get adding inside items. The old one `yrgroih9` gets removed and the next `qhy0dukj` get added while adding new key value pairs. Now i got the answer from @thedude.. Thanks for your effort..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Should be something like this:**

```
return state.setIn(
  ["appElements","layers","layer_1","items", action.objData.item_id], 
  fromJS({
      "width": action.objData.width,
      "x": action.objData.x
  }));
```

Comment: Thanks.. its working.. @thedude... but need to add close bracket ")" for setIn function in your answer..